# How to control text box trap/outset in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text-wrap, outline, trapping

In InDesign I've created a text box outlined with a double rule which overlays a graphic that I'd like it to knockout entirely from the underlying graphic. Unfortunately the knockout traps to the interior rule, not the exterior rule. Is there a way to control or establish an outset so the entire text box with outlined rules traps to the underlying graphic?

[image]

Comment: The fastest and simplest way I can think of would be to create two boxes. First the outside border one with the fill set to a color blocking the background image. Then, on top add the inner border one.

Comment: Thank you very much--that will certainly work. I was hoping there was a setting I could control because I have multiples of this design at different sizes. Automating this (if it's possible) would save me greatly.

Comment: Yup.. 2 boxes is generally the easiest way. You can't control the space between INDD's double/triple style border strokes. You could use an anchored text frame inside a shape frame.. that way it sort of stays together without the need for a group.

Comment: My bet is that the truth lies under stroke alignment options ;-) and possibly this script might come handy (not tested): https://www.scriptopedia.org/component/phocadownload/file/121-strokealignment-change-wo-shrinkfatten.html

Comment: Thank you all--will give it a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the frame has the same fill color as the background and set *Stroke > Align Stroke* to **Align Stroke to Inside**.

See here how a double stroke should react with the available 3 settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Beyond excellent--thank you WOLFF!